# Discord bot: Call a user by name?

Tags: node.js, discord

I have a little bot and want call a user with @ and his name. So he get a highlight in the channel. I wrote

```
bot.sendMessage({to: channelID, message: '@Nickname message text'});
```

But this only write @Nickname as text, without highlighting. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for mentions is actually `<@USER_ID>`. You can use [`User::mention()`](http://discordjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs_user.html#mention) to generate that string:

```
bot.sendMessage({to: channelID, message: `${user.mention()} message text`});
```

Comment: Not working for me: "TypeError: user.mention is not a function". I have change discord.io to discord.js and this working now: message.channel.send(user.toString() + ' message text'); This make a mention. Thanks for the link!