# Extract variables from json string

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, mongodb, mongoose

### **Context :**

I'm making a Discord bot using the **discord.js** library and **MongoDB** (with mongoose). I created a script that can construct messages from data stored in my MongoDB database. For exemple, if an user on my Discord server type "!hello", it will query my database to construct a reply like "Hello to you!".

I store my reply message data in an document like this :

```json
{
    "command": "!hello",
    "content": "Hello to you!"
}
```

*(I voluntary omitted some properties here that are useless in the context of my question)*

And retrieve it in my code with something like :

```js
let retrievedReply;
await mongo().then(async mongoose => {
    try {
        let query = {command: message.content};
        retrievedReply = await replySchema.findOne(query);
    } finally {
        mongoose.connection.close();
    }
});
message.reply(retrievedReply.content);
```

### **My issue :**

Now, imagine I want it to respond "Hello ***username***!".

If I didn't construct my reply using data from mongo I could simply do something like :

```js
message.reply(`Hello ${message.member.nickname}!`);
```

or

```js
message.reply("Hello " + message.member.nickname + "!");
```

So, in other words, using **backticks** and **${}** syntax or (but I like it less), splitting my string and concatenate my property value like the second example.

The thing is, we can't store a string inside backticks in json format (used by MongoDB). So even if I build my document like so :

```json
{
    "command": "hello",
    "content": "Hello ${message.member.nickname}!"
}
```

**${message.member.nickname}** would not be interpreted like a property value but just like a simple string.

## **The 1000$ question :**

How can I use this property inside my code? I thought about extracting it using regex but it does not change the fact that it will still be a string. Is there a way to "convert" from a string to an usable variable?

**EDIT**

Since Brettski asked me (rightfully), here is an example of what I want :

```js
message.member.send(`Hello ${message.member}!`);
```

This **message.member** property here represent a member object of a Discord guild. It contains a lot of things like its permissions on the guild, its roles, etc.
When we use a member object into a message, Discord will make a mention of the member like bellow.

[image: Message received from the bot into the application]

It works the same with other properties like channels for example. Users can then click on those to see informations about the member or to go directly to the channel, etc. I want to be able to use this.

Comment: set message.member.nickname equal to a variable and use that in your string

Comment: @cbracketdash Hum thanks for your comment but it doesn't change anything. The thing is I can not use variable in my string.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979335/creating-json-object-with-variables) help you out?

Comment: @0x435d2d nope, your link is the opposite of what I'm trying to do. He/she has an object with variables and he/she want to convert it into a json format. This is not what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: What if you put a token in the string and then replace it with the name? So your content could be something like `"hello ~membernickname~!"` and in or before `message.reply` do a replacement on the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, **@Brettski** put me on the right track with the fact that I can use users' or channels' IDs directly as strings within the message and between specific tags.

To reuse the example in my question, I can use this syntax to mention an user :

**"<@idOfTheUser>"**

What I did is if I want to mention the author of the command in my reply, I put the text in my mongoDB document as so :

```json
const helloCommand = {
  "command": "hello",
  "content": "Hello $member$!"
};
```

Then, in my code, I can simply use :

```
message.reply((retrieveReply.content).replace(/\$member\$/g, `<@${message.member.id}>`))
```

Of course, I wanted to use more properties so I did a function like :

```
const messageContentReplace = function(content) {
    const replaceableStrings = {
                "$member$": `<@${message.member.id}>`,
                "$memberName$": message.member.displayName,
                "$guild$": message.guild.name
    }
    return content.replace(/(\$member\$)|(\$memberName\$)|(\$guild\$)/g, match => {
        return replaceableStrings[match];
});
```

*(in reality, I did something more complexe because I use an embed message as my response with multiple fields etc... See [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed) about embeds)*

Answer (score 1):

That is correct you will not be able to store a string literal in Mongo or other way.

One though I had is to put a token in your string and then do a replace on it in `message.reply()` or before it.

example:

```json
const helloCommand = {
  "command": "hello",
  "content": "Hello ~~membernickname~~!"
};
```

In this example the token to replace is `~~membernickname~~`

You can use something like this to do the replace:

```js
const command = JSON.parse(helloCommand)
message.member.send(command.content.replace('~~membernickname~~', message.member));
```

The resulting string being sent to the `send()` command is the same. So if the nickname is @brettski, the string 'Hello @brettski' will be sent to the `send()` command.

In your example:

```js
message.reply(`Hello ${message.member.nickname}!`);
```

the part:

```js
`Hello ${message.member.nickname}!`
```

is a string literal ([template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)). What the function `message.reply()` ends up getting is 'Hello Nickname' a string. So the replace should work. As a test you can hard code the string used in `message.reply()` to a known nickname and it should provide the results you expect.

Comment: Yeah, it would work but it will still be a string. I want it to be clickable. I didn't explained it very well but in discord.js, if I use a variable that represents an user, it will be recognized by the discord client and it will be written as a mention where we can click on the name to see infos about the member, or the channel, etc.

Comment: What is it that you need to pass back to Discord? Can you show an example of what it is expecting? A reference to the place in the Discord.js api (discord.js.org) may be helpful as well.

Comment: Sorry for the response time. I edited my question in the last part.

Comment: Seeing that you are sending `messsage.reply()` a string I don't see any reason why using a replace wouldn't work. You will be sending the message with the Nickname included in the string, no different than what the literal template is doing.

Comment: Because if I just send it as a string, the name or channel or else will not be clickable and I want it to be. The replace method is simple of course but it just works with strings.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you as I should be. Can you provide a code you would write? Thanks for your time btw.

Comment: @JusteThom What I am saying is that there is no difference between `message.reply('hi @brettski')` and `message.reply(`hi ${message.member.nickname}`)` where message.member.nickname is @brettski

Comment: But there is! Because in your first example, it does not make the "@brettski" a clickable name. It's just printing the name as a string.

Comment: But there it is? I don't understand. By the way, what is the 'exact' value of `message.nickname`?

Comment: This SO answer mentions that the user id needs to be used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46081585/5836. Perhaps replace the token with `user.toString()`? Which it looks like will return the userId. If you like to setup an Activity at https://THAT.us, I will be more than happy to jump on and work through this live. I am sure we can figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for your time Brettski, I think I figured something out that I will put in here after testing it out. I have to go to sleep, it's late here in France. :)